Upload and download files with firebase and springboot
I am trying to add file downloading and uploading to my api in springboot 3. I have everything already set up, however when I try to upload an image I get an error that the POST method is not allowed. And if I try to download a file it tells me that I do not have download permission. I have configured both the project and the default storage (Test mode, without additional configurations or filters)
This is my code:

Firebase Configuration:

@Configuration
public class FirebaseConfig {
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        try {
            // Carga la clave de servicio desde el recurso
            GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
                    new ClassPathResource("firebase/serviceAccountKey.json").getInputStream()
            );

            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(credentials)
                    .setStorageBucket("myBucket.com")
                    .build();

            // Inicializa la aplicación Firebase
            if (FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
                FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error al inicializar Firebase", e);
        }
    }

}



Firebase Service:

@Service
@DependsOn("firebaseConfig")
public class FileStorageServiceImpl implements FileStorageService {
    private final Storage storage;
    private final String bucketName;

    public FileStorageServiceImpl() {
        this.storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        this.bucketName = StorageClient.getInstance().bucket().getName();
    }

    @Override
    public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file, String fileName) throws IOException {
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IOException("Cannot upload empty file");
        }
        BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, fileName);
        BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType(file.getContentType()).build();
        Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, file.getBytes());

        return blob.getMediaLink();  // O puedes usar signUrl para obtener una URL firmada
    }

    @Override
    public String getDownloadUrl(String fileName) {
        Blob blob = storage.get(BlobId.of(bucketName, fileName));
        return blob != null ? blob.signUrl(365, TimeUnit.DAYS).toString() : null;
    }

}



Firebase Endpoint:

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/firebase/")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FirebaseController {

    @Autowired
    private FileStorageService fileStorageService;
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
            String fileUrl = fileStorageService.uploadFile(file, fileName);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(Map.of("url", fileUrl, "fileName", fileName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(Map.of("error", "Failed to upload file: " + e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/download/{fileName}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getDownloadUrl(@PathVariable String fileName) {
        try {
            String downloadUrl = fileStorageService.getDownloadUrl(fileName);
            if (downloadUrl == null) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(Map.of("error", "File not found: " + fileName));
            }
            return ResponseEntity.ok(Map.of("url", downloadUrl));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(Map.of("error", "Failed to retrieve file: " + e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
}

I have tried creating a new service key (with owner level permissions), a new firebase project from scratch and a new storage.
